# SQL: getting the max value of one column and the corresponding other columns

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

```
ID|  tag  |  version
-----+-----+-----
1|  A  |  10
2|  A  |  20
3|  B  |  99
3|  C  |  30
3|  F  |  40
```

desired output:

```
1 A 10
2 A 20
3 B 99
```

How can I get the max version of every ID and the corresponding tag for that version? Speed is important (I have around 28m rows) so a nested Select won't do it. Also a simple Group by ID with a max(version) doesn't work because I also need the corresponding Tag where the version is max.

Comment: This question is asked and answered endlessly. Some of the answers are correct.

Comment: I tried a group by ID with max(version) but that doesn't work because I also need the tag

Comment: Look, there's a correct one just there ----->

Comment: There is one output per ID

Comment: SELECT id , tag , MAX(version) from table GROUP BY ID

Comment: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+oracle)

Comment: @manitaz that is not a valid groupy by expression

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` :

```
SELECT s.id,s.tag,s.version FROM (
    SELECT t.*,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.id ORDER BY t.version DESC) as rnk
   FROM YourTable t) s
WHERE s.rnk = 1
```

Comment: nested select will be very slow I assume if I have 28m rows

Comment: The nested select won't hurt the performance, its just so you'll be able to refer to `rnk` column which is evaluated in the inner query. Run the query and then decide about performace @nickpick

Comment: For some reason the output returns much less results than expected

Comment: That doesn't make sense.. this will return `1` row per `group` , meaning one row per `id` . @nickpick

Comment: 1 row per ID is what I'm expecting. The one with the highest version number.

Comment: And what do you get instead? This query should return exactly one row per `id` , without filtering any `id` . @nickpick

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
select id, max(tag) keep(dense_rank first order by VERSION desc) as tag, max(version) as version
from t group by id
```

Comment: why max(tag)? tag isn't a number. also   "FROM keyword not found where expected"

Comment: It doesn't matter. Oracle looks for values in diapason 'first order by VERSION desc'. It finds sorted VERSION  by desc(or max, it's the same) and return first founded row. Then Oracle gets Max(tag) of first returning row and because it is the single row then max works correctly.

Comment: @Nickpick "FROM keyword not found where expected"  - "from t " where t is your table.

Comment: "because it is the single row then max works correctly": so it's not necessary to put max(tag)?

Comment: See link https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rank-dense-rank-first-last-analytic-functions. It is necessary because it is analytic function. Imagine situation '3|  B  |  99' and '3|  C  |  99'. On id=3 there are two values with max VERSION = 99 the you should use max(tag)